# Is there a Qt builtin model that doesn't allow duplicate data?

Tags: model, qt4

Is there any Model of Qt that doesn't allow duplicate entries? Or should I inherit `QStandardItemModel` and make a change?

Comment: Perhaps in certain qsql models the sql database will do that for you on the back end?